# Check if an object has empty properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have the following JS Object

```
data = {
    name: "John",
    dataOfBirth: "",
    externalId: 2548,
    email: "john@email.com",
    mobile: ""
}
```

I will receive an object like this with many more properties that can be either `String`, `Integer` or `undefined`. For me to update my database, I cannot override a valid information with an empty one.

I could try `if (data.email === "") delete data.email` with all of them, but that seems unpractical to maintain.

Is there any way I can scan all properties without having to name every single one of them and remove all empty/undefined ones?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could simply loop through the object keys and check for each element if they value is blank.

```js
var data = {
        name: "John",
        dataOfBirth: "",
        externalId: 2548,
        email: "john@email.com",
        mobile: ""
    }

    for(var key in data) {
        if(data[key] === "") {
           console.log(key + " is blank. Deleting it");
           delete data[key]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Can't you do this? Or am I missing something?

```
Object.entries(data).filter(([k,v],i)=>!!v)
```

give you this:

```
"[
    [
        "name",
        "John"
    ],
    [
        "externalId",
        2548
    ],
    [
        "email",
        "john@email.com"
    ]
]"
```

`!!` will turn a value into boolean, at that stage you filter out null,NaN and undefined. Indeed, if you want to try this on nested objects, then you have to recursively do this because `!!Object()` is always true. Even better would be to recursively and asynchronously copy the object, filter out falsey primitives and pass a callback to stringify in the end.

**Edit:**

Someone below mentioned some falsey values that you might want to keep such as 0. In that case chain them:

```
v===null || v===0 || !!v //null, 0 and anything not falsey, but not undefined etc.
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: For me it's a quick hack to get rid of NaN,null,undefined etc.But if he want's to do this on deeply nested Object, then he needs to deep clone and iterate on this. The true answer would have to dig much deeper. If you think you can add some value, you are more then welcome to edit Andreas, thank you.

Comment: What if the value is 0, or some other falsy value that actually makes sense.

Comment: try to think of all these edge cases, for 0,you can do v===0 || !!v. You can extend and chain